# POST from react.js arriving as GET in node/js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, fetch

It seems that my POST request is being converted to GET somewhere in my REACT client code. This is the react code:

```
function SavePatient(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Saving Patient Data");
  console.log(patientData);

  fetch('http://localhost:3001',
  {
    Method: 'POST',
    Headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    Body: JSON.stringify(patientData),
    Cache: 'default'
  });
```

And this is the server code:

```
function requestListener(req,res) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

    console.log(req.url,req.method,req.headers);
    // console.log(req);
    //process.exit();

    const url = req.url;
    const body = [];
    let parsedBody = "";

    function readData(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
        body.push(chunk);
    }

    function endReadData(chunk) {
        parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(parsedBody);
    }

    if (url === '/savepatient') {
        const body = [];
        req.on('data', readData);
        req.on('end', endReadData); 
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
        res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        res.write('{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}');
        console.log('Saving...');
        fs.writeFileSync('storage/message.txt','TESTE');
        return res.end();
    }
    // console.log('Aqui')
    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    // res.write('<html>');
    // res.write('<head><title>MEDPRO.app server</title></head>');
    // res.write('<body><h1>Hello from the MEDPRO.app server!</h1></body>');
    // res.write('</html>');
    // res.end();
}
```

The server code works fine and I receive the POST request fine using postman. The problem is that when I send the request from my client using fetch ... it arrives as POST ... Very strange.

I expected the POST request to arrive to the served.

Testing the server with postman works find.

With my client this is the message that the server receives:

/ GET {
host: 'localhost:3001',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
accept: '*/*',
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6'
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting everything to lowercase in the `fetch` method; this should resolve the issue because it’s case sensitive.

Just like this:

```
function SavePatient(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Saving Patient Data");
  console.log(patientData);

  fetch('http://localhost:3001',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(patientData),
    cache: 'default'
  });
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I did not notice that at all! It works now!

Comment: Yeah happens to everyone sometimes. I‘m glad I could help!